# docstring: what type is an Figure instance, or axes, or any matplotlib artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib, docstring

Say I have a function that takes a matplotlib axes as one of the input arguments.

```
def my_func(ax):
  """
  A test function.

  Parameters:
  ----------
  ax : <?>
```

my question is what to write at `<>` so that my IDE could understand. For example if I write `axes` over there, pycharm wouldn't know what it is. When I call `my_func`, I can do something like `my_func(3.)` and pycharm wouldn't complain.

Same question goes for `Figure`, or any artist e.g. `quadmesh`.
Thanks!

Comment: `>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
`>>> type(fig)
<class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>`
`>>> type(ax)
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>`

Comment: Yeah I tried that before, putting `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` still doesn't do the job for me

Comment: I actually opened up some of matplotlib's modules, and found they put things like `Figure` or `Axes` in the docstring. But these won't work for me.

Comment: For ax: `plt.Axes`